# Divinities character sheets for D&D 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, npc, character-sheets

I remember finding the character sheets for some major divinities and famous npc on some D&D 3.5 manual, but now that I need them I can't find them anywhere.

In which manuals can I find this kind of info?

I'm especially interested in the levels, stats, equipment, spells, abilities and feats for Corellon Larethian, but I'd like to know where to find the others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statistics for Corellon Larethian and numerous other deities can be found, appropriately enough, in the Deities and Demigods sourcebook.

Several mortal NPCs of Greyhawk and Faerûn were printed in the Epic Level Handbook.

However, you should know the following before getting excited about the statistics:

- Both books are from 2002, technically released before the transition from 3.0 to 3.5. Slight rule inconsistencies are to be expected, but these can mostly be updated seamlessly.
- The books being old means the statistics presented are extremely dated themselves. First, they obviously can't take advantage of material published during 3.5's lifecycle. Second, they suffer from being built by designers who didn't have much experience building characters for the at-the-time new system. The overall result is that the characters' and deities' statistics are *really bad* by any modern metric.

Comment: thank you for the recomandations too. We usually play with a reasoned mix of 3.0 and 3.5 rules, using a wildely elastic rule set, so I'm not concerned as I ought to be by the stats not being well balanced.

Comment: True. I never realized the reason almost every Deity from that book was level 20 Fighter & 20 Cleric! I can understand the cleric part to a point but overall, with all the prestige classes (let alone all the expanded regular classes) out there this is just dumb (imo). But the 3.0-3.5 thing makes it understandable now.